# Python - How to extract a number from a bs4 output

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get a price from a website using BeautifulSoup and so far I have managed to get:

```
<h2>£<!-- -->199.99</h2>
```

I just want to receive '£199.99'
Is there a way to filter out the letters?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean you want the text content? Did you read the BS4 docs?

Comment: Where is your code trails?

Comment: Please go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and ask a better understandable question.

Comment: `print(soup.find("h2").text)`

Answer (score 0):

You will use `get_text` function with strip=True to clean if necessary

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = '<h2>£<!-- -->199.99</h2>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html5lib')

result = soup.find('h2').get_text(strip=True)

print(result)
#£199.99
```

Comment: you don't need to `strip` the element at all! you are dealing with `CDATA` where it's stripped silently within the source.

Comment: bad habits, on my side

Answer (score -1):

Use re?

```
import re

s = "<h2>£<!-- -->199.99</h2>"

rx_price = re.compile(r'([0-9.]+)')

content = re.sub(r'<.+?>', '', s)

print (f"£{rx_price.findall(content)[0]}")
```

Output:

```
£199.99
```

Comment: if the `OP` is using `bs4` and tagging `bs4` and that's can be done within `bs4`, why he need to use `REGEX?`